# Unable to host springboot modules into docker using docker-compose file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, devops

Unable to host my Spring Boot modules on Docker environment. Here, I am connecting Oracle database11g and Sleuth, Zipkin, RabbitMQ.

If i am not adding sleuth, Zipkin, Rabbitmq then my docker-compose file executing successfully but i am facing issues after adding these 3 features. any help....

```
Below provided one is my docker-compose file
 version: '3.5'
    
    services:
      apigateway:
        image: kolludocker/apigateway-apigateway:0.0.1-phase4
        ports:
          - "8765:8765"
        networks:
          - eurekaserver-network
        depends_on:
          - eurekaserver
          - rabbitmq  
        environment:
          EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka
          SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
          RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
          SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
          SPRING.ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit
        environment:
          - TZ="Asia/Kolkata"
          
      bankmodule:
        image: kolludocker/bank-bankmodule:0.0.1-phase6
        ports:
          - "9096:9096"
        networks:
          - eurekaserver-network
        depends_on:
          - eurekaserver
          - rabbitmq
        environment:
          EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka
        environment:
          SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
          RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
          SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
          SPRING.ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit
        environment:
          - TZ="Asia/Kolkata"
          
      customermodule:
        image: kolludocker/customer-customermodule:0.0.1-phase6
        ports:
          - "9095:9095"
        networks:
          - eurekaserver-network
        depends_on:
          - eurekaserver
          - rabbitmq
        environment:
          EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka
          environment:
          SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
          RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
          SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
          SPRING.ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit 
        environment:
          - TZ="Asia/Kolkata"
                 
      eurekaserver:
        image: kolludocker/eurekaserver-eurekaserver:0.0.1-phase3
        ports:
          - "8761:8761"
        networks:
          - eurekaserver-network
        environment:
          - TZ="Asia/Kolkata"
          
      zipkin-server:
        image: openzipkin/zipkin:2.23
        ports:
          - "9411:9411"
        networks:
          - eurekaserver-network
        depends_on:
          - rabbitmq
        environment:
          - TZ="Asia/Kolkata"
        environment:
          RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672 
           
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
        ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
        networks:
          - eurekaserver-network
        environment:
          - TZ="Asia/Kolkata"    
          
    networks:
      eurekaserver-network:
```

My customer module property file:

```
spring.application.name=customermodule
server.port=9095


#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/xe
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@systemipaddress:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=system
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# HikariCP settings
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=HikariPoolKollu

#hibernate configs
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#Disable dafault springboot loggers
#logging.pattern.console=

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:localhost:8888

#Eureka Server
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
#eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://systemipaddress:8761/eureka

#fault tolerance
#dafult attempts are 3 but we required 5 attempts try
resilience4j.retry.instances.custRetryFallback.max-attempts=5
#each request should fire after 300 sec -5 minutes
resilience4j.retry.instances.custRetryFallback.wait-duration.seconds=1
#If the request fails, wait 1 + random_number_milliseconds seconds and retry
resilience4j.retry.instances.custRetryFallback.enable-exponential-backoff=true

#CircuitBreakers
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.kollu-retry.failure-rate-threshold=50

#RateLimit
#2 requests in 300 sec's
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.kollu-retry.limit-for-period=2
resilience4j.ratelimiter.instances.kollu-retry.limit-refresh-period.seconds=300

#bulk requests
#concurrent call mean at time 10 users can send requests
resilience4j.bulkhead.instances.kollu-retry.max-concurrent-calls=10


#If we want to ignore zipkin server connectivity enable below line
#spring.zipkin.enabled=true
#spring.zipkin.baseUrl=http://zipkin-server/
#spring.zipkin.locator.discovery.enabled=true
```

Comment: What issues are you encountering?  What doesn't work, and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Error no:1    HikariPoolKollu - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.                                                                                                                                  Error2: Java Heap (reserved=4005888KB, committed=595456KB)
 (mmap: reserved=4005888KB, committed=595456KB)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for response, Now i am able host. Issue with network. I ran the oracle image in one network and my modules are running into another network, Dynamically different networks are creating with different name.